# Start a program from USB on Windows Login

Tags: .net, winapi

I want to check if a USB has been inserted when I'm at the windows Login screen, I would like to make the program disable the windows Login on start up and when the USB has been inserted it would send an ID and if that ID is correct it would enable the windows Login.

First off I would like to know if it is possible although I would like to think that in programming everything is possible..... :D , and if so any resources, help or tutorials would be much appreciated.

As for languages I was thinking C++ or C, or maybe Assembly (I'm not that proficient in Assembly though) or could this be achieved using C#, Perl, Python, or Java?

Comment: I don't think this could be done in Java, because it's not platform specific. C/C++/C# would be my best guess.

Comment: You need to write a credential provider.

Comment: Why don't you just use smart cards?

Comment: yhe C++ was my guess too, i could use smart cards, but i wanted something that is more commonly available... but thanks for the comments, anyone knows of a website where it explains starting a program from USB on the windows login screen... thanks again for your feedback :)

Comment: There are some other possibilities depending on what your requirements are. Have you looked into writing a keyboard filter driver and only allow CTRL-ALT-DEL to be allowed if the USB device is attached and giving correct ID? This would to some extent lock the login until USB device is attached.

Comment: yes i want it to send a key Eg: 2590, and if that Key that has been sent from USB matched the one stored in computer then the USB is the one that correspondent to that computer and opens windows password filed, I started programming, but went in another direction as i don't know how to do this i am creating the program to start on start up after you are logged in but still if anyone has more ideas feel free to share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need to replace winlogon.exe with a program that reads data from your USB drive and runs the actual winlogon if everything is correct (I'm not sure if that would work with anything later than XP, though). Also, you would need to set up a bios password and lock the pc case.